# Unmarshalling neo4j results to a nested struct in Golang

Tags: json, go, neo4j, unmarshalling

I'm using the neoism library (https://github.com/jmcvetta/neois) to talk to a local neo4j database - I'm fairly new to go and am new to neo4j so the gap in my understanding could be on either side of the problem.

I have a simple database, a single "page" node which is related to a single "template" node. I was hoping to be able to have struct representing each node and nest them inside one another but I'm strugging to get this to work.

Creating the simple DB:

```
template, err := ioutil.ReadFile(viewPath + "templates/default.mustache")

if err != nil{
    panic(err)
}

defaultTemplate, _ := db.CreateNode(neoism.Props{
    "name": "default",
    "content": string(template),
})

defaultTemplate.AddLabel("Template")

n0, _ := db.CreateNode(neoism.Props{
    "name": "Home",
    "slug": "home",
    "title": "Home Page",
    "content" : "here I am",
})

n0.AddLabel("Page")
n0.Relate("TEMPLATE", template.Id(), neoism.Props{})
```

Now to the business of trying to get the data back out...

Here is my query which works just fine:

```
type PageStruct struct{
    Name string `json:"p.name"`
    Slug string `json:"p.slug"`
    Title string `json:"p.title"`
    Content string `json:"p.content"`
    TemplateName string `json:"t.name"`
    TemplateContent string `json:"t.content"`

}    

res := []PageStruct{}

    cq := neoism.CypherQuery{
        Statement: `
            MATCH (p:Page)-[r:TEMPLATE]->(t:Template)
            WHERE p.slug = {slug}
            RETURN p.name, p.slug, p.title, p.content, t.name, t.content
        `,
        Parameters: neoism.Props{"slug": pageSlug},
        Result:     &res,
    }

    db.Cypher(&cq)
    page := res[0]
```

But ideally what I want is to unmarshall into a nested struct, something like this:

```
    type PageStruct struct{
        Name string `json:"p.name"`
        Slug string `json:"p.slug"`
        Title string `json:"p.title"`
        Content string `json:"p.content"`
        Template struct {
            Name string `json:"t.name"`
            Content string `json:"t.content"`
                 } `json:"t"`

}
```

I've been trying various things with no success, could anyone give me any advice on how to achieve this abitious feat of computer engineering...

Additionally I'm slightly unclear as to how to handle relationships in neo4j in the sense of having no enforcement (that I'm aware of) as to the type of relationship (e.g one-to-one, one-to-many) so how to handle this - do we always just assume an array of data?

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [embedding](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding).

```
type Page struct {
    Name string `json:"p.name"`
    // ...
    Template
}

type Template struct {
    Name string `json:"t.name"`
    // ...
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/B3ro3wgsGS.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that works perfectly for a single template, but if I attatch two template nodes to the page (I dont need to do this but will on other queries), both templates are pulled in by the query but any ideas how I would populate an array of []Template structs with my templates. including []Template in the page struct doesnt work... any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I've never worked with neo4j. You'll have to either look up the docs to see if it can generate JSON arrays (like `[{"t.name":"1"},{"t.name":"2"}]`) to unmarshal them into `[]Template`, or ask a new question about it.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help with the JSON marshalling, I shall continue to investigate next week